# Sorting a dictionary by it's nested dictionary values

Tags: python

Here is my input data:

```py
Mydict = {
'Red': {'Pesho': 1250000, 'Chicho': 101},
'Blue': {'Pesho': 10000, 'Gosho': 10000, 'Jecho': 260000},
'White': {'Bobo': 10, 'Bebo': 10, 'Bibo': 100, 'Bubo': 10}
}
```

I would like to sort the output first by the values of the nested dictionaries and then by their length. How to do that?

The output should look like this:

```
(Red) Pesho <-> 1250000
(Blue) Jecho <-> 260000
(Blue) Pesho <-> 10000
(Blue) Gosho <-> 10000
(Red) Chicho <-> 101
(White) Bibo <-> 100
(White) Bobo <-> 10
(White) Bebo <-> 10
(White) Bubo <-> 10
```

After digging a bit more, I came up with this:

```
sorted_Mydict = dict(sorted(Mydict.items(), key=lambda x: -len(x[1].values()))) #Making a new order by the count of the nested dictionarie values
pairs = [(color, name, power) for color, inner in sorted_Mydict.items() for name, power in inner.items()] #Then creating list of pairs, as suggested in the comments
[print(f"({color}) {name} <-> {power}") for color, name, power in sorted(pairs, key=lambda x: -x[2])] #Finally printing in the desired format, ordered by the int values
```

Thanks for the help to everyone!

Comment: "And then by their length" - whose length?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need to create the structure that a list of tuple of 3 elements `color, name, value`, then sort it with your criterias

```
values = {
    'Red': {'Pesho': 1250000, 'Chicho': 101},
    'Blue': {'Pesho': 10000, 'Gosho': 10000, 'Jecho': 260000},
    'White': {'Bobo': 10, 'Bebo': 10, 'Bibo': 100, 'Bubo': 10}
}

pairs = [(outer_key, inner_key, value) for outer_key, inner in values.items() 
                                       for inner_key, value in inner.items()]

pairs.sort(key=lambda x: (-x[2], len(x[1])))
print(pairs[:3])  # [('Red', 'Pesho', 1250000), ('Blue', 'Jecho', 260000), ('Blue', 'Pesho', 10000)]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not sorting, you're getting more values out than you're putting in. Also, you shouldn't use "dict" as the name for your dict, as it is a python method.
Here's a working answer though :)

```
myDict = {
'Red': {'Pesho': 1250000, 'Chicho': 101},
'Blue': {'Pesho': 10000, 'Gosho': 10000, 'Jecho': 260000},
'White': {'Bobo': 10, 'Bebo': 10, 'Bibo': 100, 'Bubo': 10}
}


def getValue(x):
    return -x["Value"] #minus to invert sort

myDictList=[]
for key1 in myDict.keys():
    for key2 in myDict[key1].keys():
        myDictList.append({"Color":key1,"Name":key2,"Value":myDict[key1][key2]})


myDictList.sort(key=getValue)
print(myDictList)
```

Comment: Yea, was working on an answer, should've waited, I'll do that next time :)

Answer (score 1):

Combine the dictionary values into a list of tuples. Sort the list using an appropriate key function.  You can then format the printed output as you like.

```
myDict = {
'Red': {'Pesho': 1250000, 'Chicho': 101},
'Blue': {'Pesho': 10000, 'Gosho': 10000, 'Jecho': 260000},
'White': {'Bobo': 10, 'Bebo': 10, 'Bibo': 100, 'Bubo': 10}
}

r = [(C,K,n) for C,d in myDict.items() for K,n in d.items()]
r.sort(key=lambda ckn:ckn[-1], reverse=True)

for C,K,n in r: print(f"({C}) {K},<-> {n}")

(Red) Pesho,<-> 1250000
(Blue) Jecho,<-> 260000
(Blue) Pesho,<-> 10000
(Blue) Gosho,<-> 10000
(Red) Chicho,<-> 101
(White) Bibo,<-> 100
(White) Bobo,<-> 10
(White) Bebo,<-> 10
(White) Bubo,<-> 10
```